# SQL Modify returned select value without union

Tags: sql, select, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to write an SQL statement that returns a list of employees by employee number, name, job_id and a modified salary depending on their job_id. If an employee is a VP the SELECT statement should return a salary with a %20 increase, but if they're a MAN it should return a salary with a %30 increase. Is it possible to return two different modified salaries without a union? Here's what I have so far.

```
SELECT 'Employee ', EMPLOYEE_ID, 
'named ', FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME AS "Full Name", 
'with Job ID of ', JOB_ID,
'will have a new salary of ', SALARY
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE ROUND(SALARY*1.2,2) IN (SELECT ROUND(SALARY*1.2,2)
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE JOB_ID LIKE '%VP')
OR ROUND(SALARY*1.3,2) IN (SELECT ROUND(SALARY*1.3,2)
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE JOB_ID LIKE '%MAN');
```

Comment: I think you mean `LIKE 'VP%` that mean start with VP and something else, right now mean end with  `VP` or end with `MAN`.

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza: Maybe that's the structure. So it could be any 'MAN', e.g. 'SUPERMAN'  or 'WOMAN' ;-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner That just prove my point ;)

Comment: Yeah it's the structure, that's why I used the wild card like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT 'Employee ', EMPLOYEE_ID, 
       'named ', FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME AS "Full Name", 
       'with Job ID of ', JOB_ID,
       'will have a new salary of ',
       salary * CASE WHEN job_id LIKE '%VP' THEN 1.2
                     WHEN job_id LIKE '%MAN' THEN 1.3
                     ELSE 1
                END
FROM   EMPLOYEES
```

Answer (score 1):

It's much simpler:

```
SELECT 
  'Employee ',
  employee_id, 
  'named ', 
  first_name || ' ' || last_name AS "Full Name", 
  'with Job ID of ',
  job_id,
  'will have a new salary of ', 
  CASE 
    WHEN job_id LIKE '%VP' THEN salary * 1.2
    WHEN job_id LIKE '%MAN' THEN salary * 1.3
    ELSE salary
  END AS modified_salary
FROM employees;
```